# How to use for loop using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to build a program using javascript and HTML whereby it will allow the students to key in the subject codes, subject names, credits and their expected marks for the semester. The codes below can be run, but there is something that needs to be done on the javascript parts. I want to shorten the script codes using the for loop.

```
<html>
<title> GPA Calculator </title>
<head>

<script src="gpa.js">
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="gpaCalc">
<table id="myTable" border="1"; width: "100%">
<tr>
    <th>Code
    <th>Subject
    <th>Credit
    <th>Expected Mark
    <th>Grades
    <th>GPA
    <th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="code" value="SCS987"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="subject" value="Object-Oriented Programming"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="credit" value="4"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="marks" oninput="getMarks()"></td>
<td id = "grade" value=""></td>
<td id = "points" value=""></td>
<td><input type="button" value="Show Grades" onclick="displayGrades('myTable')" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="code" value="SCS119"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="subject" value="Software Engineering"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="credit1" value="3"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="marks1" oninput="getMarks1()"></td>
<td id = "grade1" value=""></td>
<td id = "points1" value=""></td>
<td><input type="button" value="Show Grades" onclick="displayGrades1('myTable')" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="code" value="SCS902"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="subject" value="Operating System"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="credit2" value="3"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="marks2" oninput="getMarks2()"></td>
<td id = "grade2" value=""></td>
<td id = "points2" value=""></td>
<td><input type="button" value="Show Grades" onclick="displayGrades2('myTable')" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="code" value="SCS897"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="subject" value="Web Programming"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="credit3" value="3"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="marks3" oninput="getMarks3()"></td>
<td id = "grade3" value=""></td>
<td id = "points3" value=""></td>
<td><input type="button" value="Show Grades" onclick="displayGrades3('myTable')" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="code" value="ENG213"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="subject" value="Advanced Academic English Skills"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="credit4" value="2"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="marks4" oninput="getMarks4()"></td>
<td id = "grade4" value=""></td>
<td id = "points4" value=""></td>
<td><input type="button" value="Show Grades" onclick="displayGrades4('myTable')" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="code" value="BIO899"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="subject" value="Structure and Functions of Proteins"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="credit5" value="3"></td>
<td><input type="text" id="marks5" oninput="getMarks5()"></td>
<td id = "grade5" value=""></td>
<td id = "points5" value=""></td>
<td><input type="button" value="Show Grades" onclick="displayGrades5('myTable')" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<div id="outputDive" style="height:50px; width:100%";"></div>

<br><input type="button" value="Add Subject" onclick="addRow('myTable')" />
<input type="button" value="Calculate GPA" onclick="gpacalc()" /> 
<!---<br><input type="submit" value="Calculate GPA" onclick="xxxxxx('yyyy')" />--->
</body>
</html>
```

This is the html code and the following will be the .js file.

```
function addRow(myTable)
{
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    cell1.appendChild(element1);

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    cell2.appendChild(element2);

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var element3 = document.createElement("input");
    cell3.appendChild(element3);

    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    var element4 = document.createElement("input");
    cell4.appendChild(element4);

    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
    var element5 = document.createElement("");
    cell5.appendChild(element5);

    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
    var element6 = document.createElement("");
    cell6.appendChild(element6);
}

var x;
function getMarks()
{
    x = document.getElementById("marks").value;
}

function displayGrades(myTable)
{
    var grade;
    var gpaPoint;
    if(x >= 90 && x<=100)
    {
        grade = "A+";
        gpaPoint = 4.00;
    }

    else if(x >=80 && x< 90)
    {
        grade = "A";
        gpaPoint = 4.00;
    }

    else if(x >=75 && x< 80)
    {
        grade = "A-";
        gpaPoint = 3.67;
    }

    else if(x >=70 && x< 75)
    {
        grade = "B+";
        gpaPoint = 3.33;
    }

    else if(x >=65 && x< 70)
    {
        grade = "B";
        gpaPoint = 3.00;
    }

    else if(x >=60 && x< 65)
    {
        grade = "B-";
        gpaPoint = 2.67;
    }

    else if(x >=55 && x< 60)
    {
        grade = "C+";
        gpaPoint = 2.33;
    }

    else if(x >=50 && x< 55)
    {
        grade = "C";
        gpaPoint = 2.00;
    }

    else if(x >=45 && x< 50)
    {
        grade = "C-";
        gpaPoint = 1.67;
    }

    else if(x >=40 && x< 45)
    {
        grade = "D";
        gpaPoint = 1.00;
    }

    else if(x < 40)
    {
        grade = "F";
        gpaPoint = 0.00;
    }

    document.getElementById("grade").innerHTML = grade;
    document.getElementById("points").innerHTML = gpaPoint;
}

var x;
function getMarks1()
{
    x = document.getElementById("marks1").value;
}

function displayGrades1(myTable)
{
    var grade;
    var gpaPoint;
    if(x >= 90 && x<=100)
    {
        grade = "A+";
        gpaPoint = 4.00;
    }

    else if(x >=80 && x< 90)
    {
        grade = "A";
        gpaPoint = 4.00;
    }

    else if(x >=75 && x< 80)
    {
        grade = "A-";
        gpaPoint = 3.67;
    }

    else if(x >=70 && x< 75)
    {
        grade = "B+";
        gpaPoint = 3.33;
    }

    else if(x >=65 && x< 70)
    {
        grade = "B";
        gpaPoint = 3.00;
    }

    else if(x >=60 && x< 65)
    {
        grade = "B-";
        gpaPoint = 2.67;
    }

    else if(x >=55 && x< 60)
    {
        grade = "C+";
        gpaPoint = 2.33;
    }

    else if(x >=50 && x< 55)
    {
        grade = "C";
        gpaPoint = 2.00;
    }

    else if(x >=45 && x< 50)
    {
        grade = "C-";
        gpaPoint = 1.67;
    }

    else if(x >=40 && x< 45)
    {
        grade = "D";
        gpaPoint = 1.00;
    }

    else if(x < 40)
    {
        grade = "F";
        gpaPoint = 0.00;
    }

    document.getElementById("grade1").innerHTML = grade;
    document.getElementById("points1").innerHTML = gpaPoint;
}

var x;
function getMarks2()
{
    x = document.getElementById("marks2").value;
}

function displayGrades2(myTable)
{
    var grade;
    var gpaPoint;
    if(x >= 90 && x<=100)
    {
        grade = "A+";
        gpaPoint = 4.00;
    }

    else if(x >=80 && x< 90)
    {
        grade = "A";
        gpaPoint = 4.00;
    }

    else if(x >=75 && x< 80)
    {
        grade = "A-";
        gpaPoint = 3.67;
    }

    else if(x >=70 && x< 75)
    {
        grade = "B+";
        gpaPoint = 3.33;
    }

    else if(x >=65 && x< 70)
    {
        grade = "B";
        gpaPoint = 3.00;
    }

    else if(x >=60 && x< 65)
    {
        grade = "B-";
        gpaPoint = 2.67;
    }

    else if(x >=55 && x< 60)
    {
        grade = "C+";
        gpaPoint = 2.33;
    }

    else if(x >=50 && x< 55)
    {
        grade = "C";
        gpaPoint = 2.00;
    }

    else if(x >=45 && x< 50)
    {
        grade = "C-";
        gpaPoint = 1.67;
    }

    else if(x >=40 && x< 45)
    {
        grade = "D";
        gpaPoint = 1.00;
    }

    else if(x < 40)
    {
        grade = "F";
        gpaPoint = 0.00;
    }

    document.getElementById("grade2").innerHTML = grade;
    document.getElementById("points2").innerHTML = gpaPoint;
}

var x;
function getMarks3()
{
    x = document.getElementById("marks3").value;
}

function displayGrades3(myTable)
{
    var grade;
    var gpaPoint;
    if(x >= 90 && x<=100)
    {
        grade = "A+";
        gpaPoint = 4.00;
    }

    else if(x >=80 && x< 90)
    {
        grade = "A";
        gpaPoint = 4.00;
    }

    else if(x >=75 && x< 80)
    {
        grade = "A-";
        gpaPoint = 3.67;
    }

    else if(x >=70 && x< 75)
    {
        grade = "B+";
        gpaPoint = 3.33;
    }

    else if(x >=65 && x< 70)
    {
        grade = "B";
        gpaPoint = 3.00;
    }

    else if(x >=60 && x< 65)
    {
        grade = "B-";
        gpaPoint = 2.67;
    }

    else if(x >=55 && x< 60)
    {
        grade = "C+";
        gpaPoint = 2.33;
    }

    else if(x >=50 && x< 55)
    {
        grade = "C";
        gpaPoint = 2.00;
    }

    else if(x >=45 && x< 50)
    {
        grade = "C-";
        gpaPoint = 1.67;
    }

    else if(x >=40 && x< 45)
    {
        grade = "D";
        gpaPoint = 1.00;
    }

    else if(x < 40)
    {
        grade = "F";
        gpaPoint = 0.00;
    }

    document.getElementById("grade3").innerHTML = grade;
    document.getElementById("points3").innerHTML = gpaPoint;
}

var x;
function getMarks4()
{
    x = document.getElementById("marks4").value;
}

function displayGrades4(myTable)
{
    var grade;
    var gpaPoint;
    if(x >= 90 && x<=100)
    {
        grade = "A+";
        gpaPoint = 4.00;
    }

    else if(x >=80 && x< 90)
    {
        grade = "A";
        gpaPoint = 4.00;
    }

    else if(x >=75 && x< 80)
    {
        grade = "A-";
        gpaPoint = 3.67;
    }

    else if(x >=70 && x< 75)
    {
        grade = "B+";
        gpaPoint = 3.33;
    }

    else if(x >=65 && x< 70)
    {
        grade = "B";
        gpaPoint = 3.00;
    }

    else if(x >=60 && x< 65)
    {
        grade = "B-";
        gpaPoint = 2.67;
    }

    else if(x >=55 && x< 60)
    {
        grade = "C+";
        gpaPoint = 2.33;
    }

    else if(x >=50 && x< 55)
    {
        grade = "C";
        gpaPoint = 2.00;
    }

    else if(x >=45 && x< 50)
    {
        grade = "C-";
        gpaPoint = 1.67;
    }

    else if(x >=40 && x< 45)
    {
        grade = "D";
        gpaPoint = 1.00;
    }

    else if(x < 40)
    {
        grade = "F";
        gpaPoint = 0.00;
    }

    document.getElementById("grade4").innerHTML = grade;
    document.getElementById("points4").innerHTML = gpaPoint;
}

var x;
function getMarks5()
{
    x = document.getElementById("marks5").value;
}

function displayGrades5(myTable)
{
    var grade;
    var gpaPoint;
    if(x >= 90 && x<=100)
    {
        grade = "A+";
        gpaPoint = 4.00;
    }

    else if(x >=80 && x< 90)
    {
        grade = "A";
        gpaPoint = 4.00;
    }

    else if(x >=75 && x< 80)
    {
        grade = "A-";
        gpaPoint = 3.67;
    }

    else if(x >=70 && x< 75)
    {
        grade = "B+";
        gpaPoint = 3.33;
    }

    else if(x >=65 && x< 70)
    {
        grade = "B";
        gpaPoint = 3.00;
    }

    else if(x >=60 && x< 65)
    {
        grade = "B-";
        gpaPoint = 2.67;
    }

    else if(x >=55 && x< 60)
    {
        grade = "C+";
        gpaPoint = 2.33;
    }

    else if(x >=50 && x< 55)
    {
        grade = "C";
        gpaPoint = 2.00;
    }

    else if(x >=45 && x< 50)
    {
        grade = "C-";
        gpaPoint = 1.67;
    }

    else if(x >=40 && x< 45)
    {
        grade = "D";
        gpaPoint = 1.00;
    }

    else if(x < 40)
    {
        grade = "F";
        gpaPoint = 0.00;
    }

    document.getElementById("grade5").innerHTML = grade;
    document.getElementById("points5").innerHTML = gpaPoint;
}

function gpacalc()
{
    var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("points").value);
    var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("points1").value);
    var c = parseFloat(document.getElementById("points2").value);
    var d = parseFloat(document.getElementById("points3").value);
    var e = parseFloat(document.getElementById("points4").value);
    var f = parseFloat(document.getElementById("points5").value);
    var totalPoint = a+b+c+d+e+f;

    var cr1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("credit").value);
    var cr2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("credit1").value);
    var cr3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("credit2").value);
    var cr4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("credit3").value);
    var cr5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("credit4").value);
    var cr6 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("credit5").value);
    var totalCr = cr1+cr2+cr3+cr4+cr5+cr6;

    var display = document.getElementById('outputDiv');
    display.innerHTML="Your GPA is: "+totalPoint/totalCr;
}
```

Comment: You don't aware with looping concept in programming?

Comment: @DivyeshGauswami I am not familiar with the loop concept in javascript. + my case requires me to use the for loop to access each elements in the table. I'm still a beginner by the way.

Comment: Okay no problem. Just go through w3cschool/javascrip and learn it.. it is pretty simple and easy and same concept as use in other lang. :) my suggestion to you that describe your que. In brief so that other can come to know what actually probelm is

Comment: the examples provided on w3schools are very simple that i do not know how to implement them into my case. The problem with my .js code is that it is too long and quite complicated if the student would wish to add a new subject later on. And I don't really know how to explain this further , sorry.

Comment: Okay, tomorrow i will try to solve ur problem.. :)

Comment: @DivyeshGauswami right..

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic variable names:

This can be done in a javascript with eval(..):

eval('') evaluates dynamically created String:

```
function addRow(myTable)
{
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);


    for(var i=1; i < 7; ++i)
    {

        var varcell = "cell" + i;
        var varelement = "element" +i;

        var cell == eval(varcell);
        var element == eval(varelement);

        row.insertCell(i-1);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        cell1.appendChild(element1);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. but i need to use the for loop to determine the grade that a student obtained based on the marks that they have entered in the form.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single function for getting grade and point by giving the percent value.

```
function getGradeAndPoint(p) {
    if (x < 40) {
        return { grade: "F", gpaPoint: 0.00 };
    }
    if (x < 45) {
        return { grade: "D", gpaPoint: 1.00 };
    }
    if (x < 50) {
        return { grade: "C-", gpaPoint: 1.67 };
    }
    if (x < 55) {
        return { grade: "C", gpaPoint: 2.00 };
    }
    if (x < 60) {
        return { grade: "C+", gpaPoint: 2.33 };
    }
    if (x < 65) {
        return { grade: "B-", gpaPoint: 2.67 };
    }
    if (x < 70) {
        return { grade: "B", gpaPoint: 3.00 };
    }
    if (x < 75) {
        return { grade: "B+", gpaPoint: 3.33 };
    }
    if (x < 80) {
        return { grade: "A-", gpaPoint: 3.67 };
    }
    if (x < 90) {
        return { grade: "A", gpaPoint: 4.00 };
    }
    return { grade: "A+", gpaPoint: 4.00 };
}
```

With

```
var object = getGradeAndPoint(82);
```

you get the result as an object, like

```
{
    grade: "A",
    gpaPoint: 4.00
}
```

and the access to the values is possible with the keys, like

```
object.grade
```

Comment: what is the p for?

Comment: i assume, this is the percent value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out all the common jobs you are performing, then identify some common variable to distinguish them. for example, you can use **id** to pass in the **grade** method.

```js
function getMarks(id) {
  x = document.getElementById(id).value;
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="code" value="SCS987"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="subject" value="Object-Oriented Programming"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="credit" value="4"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="marks" oninput="getMarks(this.id)"></td>
  <td id="grade" value=""></td>
  <td id="points" value=""></td>
  <td><input type="button" value="Show Grades" onclick="displayGrades('myTable')" /></td>
</tr>
```

Identify the same for other options like displayGrades, etc.

Answer to your question i.e. how to use for loop. Its just sample which give you the idea.

```js
function addRow(myTable) {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    var cell = row.insertCell(i);
    if (i < 4) {
      // As you want to create a input field just before 
      var element = document.createElement("input");
      // you need ID attributes to pass on for getMarks
      element.id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + "Id";
      cell.appendChild(element);
    }
  }
}
```

You just need to go through your code and highlight the common action which will optimise your code. Also, go through looping concept to understand it easily.

Comment: i have 2 id's for displayGrades(), which are id="grade" and id="points". how do i include them in one method?

Comment: I have tried to use the id to pass in the grade but it only works for the first row. this is what i meant by implementing a for loop

Comment: It should not. have you changed the html accordingly `<td><input type="text" id="marks1" oninput="getMarks(this.id)"></td>`. You will always get the id of that particular row. You need to check first the row you are editing and then fetch the column you need to update based on the rowindex in case of 2 id's for displayGrades,

Comment: i did. but it only display the grade and points on the first row whenever i clicked on the show grades button. for example, i entered a mark in the second row, but the value of the grade and points are updated only on the first row instead of the second row.

Comment: and I don't know what you mean by check the row and then fetch the column that i need to update based on the rowindex. (Sorry for you have to explain a lot to me).